# Use if in the state component in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, profile

So im creating a profile pic, but a pass the user is in a react navigation and it gives an error when I want to enter with my user, here is the code:

```
export default class Profile extends Component{
  state = {
    errorMessage: null,
    project:[],
    user:{
     id:  this.props.route.params.name  //here is where it gives the error i want to find a way to make something like if (undefined) async storage ....
    }
  }
    
  getUser = async() => {
      try{
        console.log('1')
        const usu =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@backend:user')
        console.log('2')
        userID = this.state.user.id
        console.log('3')
        console.log(userID)
        const response = await api.get(`/auth/` + userID)
        console.log('4')
        console.log(response.data)
   
        const { project } = response.data
        console.log('5')
        this.setState({ project })
       }catch (response){
         this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error})
     }
    
    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set it to undefined and then do some setState in componentDidMount for example.

But you could also use a ***ternary Operator*** in react native.

```
id: this.props.route.params.name ? this.props.route.params.name : undefined
```

this code checks if the param exists and takes it, if it does not exist it will set the state to undefined.

You can also do some extra checks like:

```
id: this.props.route.params.name == "myname" ? this.props.route.params.name : undefined
```

In that case if the name is **myname** it would set it if not it would set it to **undefined**.

more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html